# How does the ".NET for Metro style apps" reference in VS11 Beta work, exactly?

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When you create a new C# Metro style app in VS11 beta, it only has two references: one to Windows.winmd, which is a file and I get that; and one to ".NET for Metro style apps", which appears to point to the .NETCore folder under Reference Assemblies and not to any file in particular. The File Type property for both references is "SDK".

Am I right in guessing that the folder reference effectively references every file in that folder? Are there any particular compile-time things that go on there that are interesting? Is there a way I can create a folder which can be referenced the same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build the project using `msbuild` on the console you will be able to see what **exactly** is happening. All the .Net references are passed to the compiler as `/reference` compiler option, so I don't think there is anything special or interesting happening there on the compile time.

It seems that there is some special work done on `msbuild` to include the references for Windows SDK and .Net, rather than a standard feature that can be used for other purposes. If you open the `csproj` file you can see that all .Net and Windows references are added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can see this when you bump up the build verbosity, Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, Build and Run, MSBuild project build output verbosity setting.  It gets interesting just after "TargetMonikerDisplayName" with a message that shows what reference assemblies it calculates and the `Task "Csc"` notification that shows the command line options being passed to the C# compiler.

You'll see it passes them *all*.  I've got 71 references assemblies in the .NETCore\v4.5 directory and the compiler gets 72 /reference options, 1 extra for Windows.winmd

So you can always write code like this in a C# Metro app ;)

```
        string newline = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Constants.vbCrLf;
```